# Makefile with Pro*C cannot find .c file

Tags: c, oracle, makefile, precompiler

I have a directory of .pc files, and I am trying to compile to .o files with a Makefile. Oracle Pro*C precompiles the .pc files into .c. Then gcc compiles the .c files to .o. These are the rules:

```
%.c: %.pc
    $(PROC) $(PROCPLSFLAGS)  INCLUDE=$(SRCHOME) iname=$<
%.o: %.c 
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) $(PRECOMPPUBLIC) -c $<
```

The problem occurs when I try to build a `.o` file. The `.c` file is generated correctly, but the `$(CC)` line cannot find the `.c` file until I run make a second time. When I run the Makefile without any arguments to build the entire directory, I need to run make twice for each `.pc` file in the directory. How can I fix the Makefile so that it only needs to run once?

Comment: What you have shown us should already do what you want it to do, which means the problem is in something you haven't shown us.  Please attempt to construct a [MCVE] by starting with your full makefile and then deleting bits from it until you can no longer reproduce the problem yourself.  Then put back the last bit and post that makefile.

Comment: maybe like this> (rule 1) .pc.c $(PROC) $(PROCPLSFLAGS)  INCLUDE=$(SRCHOME) iname=$*.pc (rule2) .c.o: $(CC) $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) $(PRECOMPPUBLIC) $*